# trackers not showing after making camera solver

Tags: video, tracking

I've been tracking a video but when I add the object constraint "camera solver" trackers aren't showing in the 3D view...can you help me, please?
Thank you

Comment: Did you solve the scene? Did you press the "Setup tracking scene" button? did you enable the "motion tracking" visibility in the 3D viewport? https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVgrC.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable Motion Tracking in the 3D viewport.

[image]

For 2.8 the option is found as an overlay.

[image]